# Как создать такой эффект прокрутки?

Tags: jquery, css

Вот ссылка http://www.royrobson.com/ru/o-kompanii/
Как сделать чтобы картинки тоже были фоном и прокручивалась только область видимости с текстовыми блоками?

Comment: этот эффект называется Parallax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно поставить для блока на background картинку и задать background-attachment: fixed;
Вот небольшой пример сделал:

http://codepen.io/prevolley/pen/jrErvX?editors=1100

```
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/600/400") no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
```

Немного коряво, но сам принцип будет понятен

Comment: Спасибо! Именно это и искал!

Answer (score 0):

Делал так:

```
<div id="separator_2" class="separator1">
<div class="bg3 bg"></div>
<p class="separator"></p>
</div>
```

css:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
    .separator1 .bg, .back-image .bg, .back-contact .bg, #intro .bg1 {
        background-attachment: fixed !important;
    }
}


/* #Separators
================================================== */

p.separator {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 38px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 200;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 240px;
}

.separator1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

.separator1 .bg {
    background: url(../images/vodopad.jpg) repeat center;
    background-size: cover !important;
    -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 200;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}

.separator1 .bg3 {
    background: url(../images/raduga.jpg) repeat center;
    background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.........jpg')
}
```